# How to convert back from string to Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, type-conversion

I have a a class which is made of property information of a target(like type and values ). Iam using this UI to show all types on view in graphical format like Enum with comboboxes and boolean with checkboxes.Everything works well for me except the case when I change combobox value in UI,it does not change in viewmodel.Every time I change value in combobox it calls convertback method in my converter.I need to convert this  string to enum type,I can write the convertback code easily for a particular enum type ,but how can I convert all other enums with this converter,I have the information of Type in PropertyType property that I can pass to converter and use it but I have no idea how to do it.

This is my UI code (only relevant part)

```
    <!-- Default DataTemplate -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  FontWeight="Bold"  />
            <TextBox Margin="8,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"  />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate for Booleans -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
            <CheckBox Margin="8,0" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>



    <!-- DataTemplate for Enums -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
            <ComboBox Margin="8,0" SelectedItem="{Binding Value,Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyType, 
                      Converter={local:EnumToListConverter}}" Grid.Column="1"  
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->
    <local:PropertyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultnDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          BooleanDataTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanDataTemplate}" 
          EnumDataTemplate="{StaticResource EnumDataTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Model,Converter={StaticResource PropConverter}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
             />
```

and my converter and view model

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string EnumString;
        try
        {
            EnumString = Enum.GetName((value.GetType()), value);
            return EnumString;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }



    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
        //What to do here
    }
```

View model

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    private PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    private object baseObject;

    public PropertyValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object baseObject)
    {
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        this.baseObject = baseObject;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return propertyInfo.Name; }

    }

    public Type PropertyType { get { return propertyInfo.PropertyType; } }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return propertyInfo.GetValue(baseObject, null); }
        set
        {

            propertyInfo.SetValue(baseObject, value , null);


        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its feasible to do this with converter or with multibinding.I solved my problem by not using the converter for combobox and checking value in getter and setter.

I modified my class which holds the property info and it works now,I am putting a special check for enum type ,rest of the types I can use converters.

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    private PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    private object baseObject;

    public PropertyValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object baseObject)
    {
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        this.baseObject = baseObject;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return propertyInfo.Name; }

    }

    public Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return propertyInfo.PropertyType; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            var retVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(baseObject, null);
            if (PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                retVal = retVal.ToString();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                value = Enum.Parse(propertyInfo.PropertyType, value.ToString());
            }
            propertyInfo.SetValue(baseObject, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont like corrupting view model for that but I cant see any option at this moment.Please let me know if there are any risks in my code or if you have a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
return (targetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(targetType), value.ToString());
```

Comment: That's close, but there are a few problems with the code. You can't cast to a `Type` variable at runtime.  A cast is also unnecessary as `IValueConverter` methods return `object`.

Comment: Error:"Cant resolve symbol targetType".  I dont think we can use targetType like this.This is not right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In ConvertBack, is targetType the correct enum type?

If so, I think this should work:

```
Enum.Parse(targetType, (String)value)
```

Comment: I got this error with your code in Convertback Error :"Type provided must be an Enum".  After debugging I see targetType is System.Object in convertback method.

Comment: @TRS In that case you might have to see if you can pass the Enum type as the converter parameter. It's really difficult to get this to bind correctly, but it's quite easy if you can put it in statically. Then you can use `(Type)parameter` instead of `targetType`

Comment: Thats exactly my question was ,Its easy to put statically,but in that case I need converter for each enum type and my datatemplate will be of no use.I have PropertyType property,I just want to know if I can make use of that for conversion.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misread.  Unfortunately I can't think of an easy way to do this.  I was going to suggest a MultiBinding, but the ConvertBack method there takes a single value and expects an array returned.  I'll have a play around tonight and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud do it like this

```
enum Colors { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4, Yellow = 8 };
string colorName = "Blue";
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorName))  //true
 {
     Colors clr = (Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorName);
 }

 colorName = "Orange";
 if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorName)) //false
 {
      Colors clr = (Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorName);
 }
```

Comment: :Thanks for your answer,but my problem is I cannot specify specific enum types ,I am trying to read all the properties of a class and show them on a form (something like a property grid) .So my class could be anything at runtime so its difficult to point specific Enum.

Answer (score 0):

What I could think quickly is that you can create one class EnumDescriptor with just two properties: EnumString (string) and EnumType (Type)

Your "EnumToListConverter" can return list of EnumDescriptor and you can bind display value of combobox to EnumString property.

In your "EnumToStringConverter", in Convert() you can create instance of EnumDescriptor as we have type and name of enum there, in ConvertBack() you will get the instance of EnumDescriptor from where you can parse the enum value and return it.

Thanks